# How to remove package from for GCM configuration?

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I am using [THIS PAGE](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart&cnturl=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Cloud%20Messaging) to generate configuration file for GCM APIs.

I accidentally added a duplicate staging flavored package name: `stag` apart from `staging`. I wonder if there is any way to remove it? I cannot find the package list in Google develop console anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [Console -> Manage all projects](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/projects) there should probably be a project that relates to your incorrectly entered package. If you delete the project, the package will no longer be visible in the list (be sure not to delete something thats actually needed :P).

Comment: But I don't know to delete the whole project just a particular package...

Comment: But the package is linked to a particular project. If there was no project that relates to this particular WRONG package, it wouldn't show up in the list.